# Food over friendship

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is supposed to be pretty simple so don't overthink it. Four friends, Larry, Ivan, Tom and Sam, all want to eat a well-drawn apple. Can you tell which of them can get to it?

[image: Empty grid]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The person who gets the apple is:

> **Tom**

Because this is:

> a **[LITS puzzle](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/lits-rules-and-info/)**, as clued by the initials of the four friends, **L**arry, **I**van, **T**om, and **S**am.  This involves placing exactly one L, I, T or S tetromino in each thick-bordered space such that no area of 2x2 cells is fully shaded, all shapes form a single interconnected shaded area, and no two touching shapes are identical.

**Step 1:**

> Start by realising that the space containing the apple and the one to its left must be shaded (to avoid a 2x2 square), and blanking out two impossible cells directly above it, as well as all the cells in the largest area that cannot be filled while connecting between the two spaces either side of it.
>
>  [image: Step 1a]
>
>  Then realise the apple's space cannot contain an L-tetromino, or it is impossible to place a shape in the top leftmost space without forming a 2x2 shape. The third cell in row 3 must be shaded.
>
>  [image: Step 1b]

**Step 2:**

Next, realise that:

> The space to the right of the apple *must contain an S-tetromino*, and that therefore the one to the right of *that* **cannot contain an S-tetromino**. There is now only one place in that space where a tetromino can be legally placed - an L-tetromino in the bottom-left corner:
>
>  [image: Step 2]

**Step 3:**

> For continuity, this fixes an S-tetromino directly above it, an I-tetromino to its right, and an L-tetromino in the bottom-right corner space in order to link to the other space above it.
>
>  [image: Step 3a]
>
>  Now there is only one way to resolve the top-leftmost corner, and the space on the right must be filled with an S-tetromino, as two L-tetrominoes cannot be adjacent. This creates a shaded path leading all the way from **Tom** to the apple!
>
>  [image: Step 3b]

Comment: And here I thought the answer was rot13(juvpurire grgebzvab funqrq gur nccyr)! At least they give the same answer